# Latex Remove Dot From References

Tags: latex, reference, pdftex

When I reference a figure with `Figure \ref{fig:myfig}`, there is a dot after the figure number: `Figure 4.`. How do I get rid of that dot?

Comment: Just for the record, TeX questions are more suited to http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Running figure numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35953/running-figure-numbering)